# Forced resignation/sexual + religous harassment + injury

Tags: resignation, termination, fraud, religion

I applied and got a job around Thanksgiving, but I turned down the offer. The company gave my resume to a manager from a different company anyway. I was contacted a week before Christmas of 2018 asking me to interview. I interviewed on Christmas eve and I got an email stating I got the job on New Year's Eve.

My 2nd day on the job and my supervisor says to me, Hey i think the community manager is asking him to do something against company policy but that he wasnt sure. That something was sell off company property to obtain a christmas bonus that the manager was mad about not getting from the company that year.

My supervisor had clear texts and evidence of the community managers askings of him to do such tasks. Sell property because Susan said it was ok. We still to this day dont know who susan is. A couple weeks go by and the manager had that supervisor of mine constructively discharged dut to alleged hostility reports on on him and accusations that "he" is the one stealing the appliances and selling them, and that the manager himself was to pass along all proceeds to upper-management. We have proof that is not the case. So my supervisor quit due to false allegations.

During the nest weeks my dog is dying and getting chemo, he was stage 5. I reported a broken pinky and i was given only an email to submit a hair follice test, nothing more. I fought for weeks asking for an avenue to have it looked at to no avail.

The community manager knew i was religious, he kept saying inappropriate things. All day long he cursed as my cross hung out of my shirt on my necklace, he wouldn't stop. I asked in front of ALL employees to respect my religion and watch what you say if you think its offensive then please don't say it in my presence. My supervisor agreed and with my request. After he quit the behavior amped up until the day of my dogs death. Then it turned into GODSPEED MY CHILD and do a sign of the cross as i asked to leave early to put my dog down in the hospital. He began saying that to all my workorders i went off to do on that day forward, he would text me in a cursing manner -- it didn't stop.

On top of this the receptionist insinuated i had a one set going on and she was going to call me names from now on. I said i prefer you not, but from that day forth she called me names. I requested in texts and emails over and over to all superiors for them to stop the behavior. You know what the uppers said. We have accepted your resignation according to what the receptionist told us you turned in your keys. Which i did not btw. I turmned them in after the so called resignation email saying for me to turn them in or face the cops. They kept all my tools which my grandfather who passed gave me. They kept my last two weeks of pay checks and never payed me. I was to go to court for a retsraining order in which the community manager said i made threats of having a firearm which i did not or was i hostile at any point. The asst manager who witnessed ALL of this seemed honest and admitted to me the last time we spoke that yes she agrees and she is sorry to wintess it all. I was blocKed form speaking to her. I feel this is all fraud and injuryand loss of tools, pay, dignity. i contacted a lawyer today and we are meeting next week, but what are some thoughts? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need legal advice. You will get legal advice. Until then, there is nothing we can do here.

Comment: Some of your paragraphs are hard to read and make sense of. In preparation to your meeting with a lawyer, it might be good to write your thoughts down like you did here, then run them through a spellchecker, then let them lie for a day and read them again. Correct any errors or open questions. Maybe let another person you trust read over it and fill in any question they have after reading it. Lawyers are *expensive*. Pay them for legal advice, don't waste your money to have them spellcheck or wonder over grammar or missing information.

Answer (score 4):

You've got a quintessential hostile workplace here, and it's entirely possible that they've violated multiple laws in how they've treated you, depending on where you're located. You've contacted a lawyer? Talk to them about it, and bring all the evidence you have with you. Make sure that when the lawsuit goes ahead, you subpeona them for all the records they kept of their communications with you (emails, etc) during the discovery process.

Bare minimum, you should be able to sue them to get them to return your grandfather's tools, since those are your personal property that they've stolen.